# sed: how to remove range of lines in file that is bounded by comment lines?

Tags: sed

Example file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
# <docker-registry>
docker.local 127.0.0.1
# </docker-registry>
```

Using the range expression feature of sed (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236754), I would like to remove the following lines:

```
# <docker-registry>
docker.local 127.0.0.1
# </docker-registry>
```

After a dozen tries with different syntaxes, this is the best I could come up with:

`sed -n 's|# <docker-registry>|,|# </docker-registry>|p' $FILE`

Without the `s` flag, I get the following error:

`sed: 1: "|# <docker-registry>|,| ...": invalid command code |`

With the `s` flag, I get the following error:

`sed: 1: "s|# <docker-registry>|, ...": bad flag in substitute command: '#'`

How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will receive the result on stdout:

```
sed -e '/# <docker-registry>/,/# <\/docker-registry>/d' yourdatafile
```

If you need to edit the data file, use ed instead of sed. Do not use redirection to the file you are reading from, as it may damage the file.

Ed script:

```
/# <docker-registry>/,/# <\/docker-registry>/d
w
q
```

call:

```
ed yourdatafile <script.ed
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:**

```
sed '/# <docker-registry>/,/# <\/docker-registry>/d' $FILE > "$FILE.tmp"
mv "$FILE.tmp" $FILE
```

**EXPLANATION:**

I found the answer as I was posting the question, so for posteriority:

1. In order to delete lines from a sed output, add the `d` flag at the end of the expression:

`sed -n 's|# <docker-registry>|,|# </docker-registry>|d' $FILE`

2. sed produces streams. In order to overwrite the file, pipe the result to the file:

`sed -n 's|# <docker-registry>|,|# </docker-registry>|d' $FILE > $FILE`

3. The `sed: 1: "s|# <docker-registry>|, ...": bad flag in substitute command: '#'` error can be avoided by using the default separator and escaping the / in the end pattern:

`sed '/# <docker-registry>/,/# <\/docker-registry>/d' $FILE > $FILE`

4. For some reason the above command in (3) wipes the original file and does not pipe the new content in there. Printing into a new file and then moving it over the old one does the trick:

```
sed '/# <docker-registry>/,/# <\/docker-registry>/d' $FILE > "$FILE.tmp"
mv "$FILE.tmp" $FILE
```

Feel free to edit if you have a more elegant answer :)

Comment: or `sed '\|# <docker-registry>|,\|# </docker-registry>|d' "$FILE" > "$FILE"`